# how to determine if user disabled Notification Center for Push Notficiations?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I know I can determine if a user disabled badges and sound for push notifications

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

if(types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge){
    NSLog(@"BADGE activated");
}

if(types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound){
    NSLog(@"SOUND activated");
}

//etc...
```

But this is not affected if the user disables the notification center under

```
Settings -> Notifications -> <Appname> -> "Show in Notification Center" to NO
```

So how do I find this out in my app if the user disables this? I googled a while and found it´s not possible but I don´t want to believe it so if anybody knows a solution it would be great to share it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation is clear :

> **enabledRemoteNotificationTypes**
>   Returns the types of notifications the app accepts.

So it returns what kind of notification types you have registered your app to with the method `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:`

Your app has no visibility on notification types allowed by users.

However, when you register your app for push notifications, it trigs the delegate method  `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` if user allow one of the notification type your app is registered to.

It weird but you are notified if user allow notification, but not if he doesn't...

Server side, Apple give you feedback for failed push notification. It means that app is not present anymore one this device. Look at [The Feedback Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This is not clear. If you don't disable any individual option is settings, but the one "Allow Notifications" switch, you will still receive a value greater than 0.

Comment: Your app doesn't have any visibility on what is allowed or not in the device's settings. It only know what kind of notifications is set to be used within the app with `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:`

Comment: I'm sorry, my comment applies for iOS8, I didn't remember this was different in iOS7, Apple changed things and in iOS8 it's really easy to achieve what I wanted